# mousemove is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery mousemove event, here is my code

```
<div id="a1" style="width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px; position:absolute">
  <div id="tracker1">
  </div>
</div>


$(a1).mousemove(function(event) {
   var x = event.pageX;
   var y = event.pageY;
   var absolutePositionx = x - $('#a1').offset().left;
   var absolutePositiony = y - $('#a1').offset().top;

   $("#tracker1").css({
     left: absolutePositionx,
     top: absolutePositiony
   });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/amw2oou9/)

The problem is when I move mouse slowly on border, there is a chance that the tracker(red dot) will move out of element which is pretty weird and should not happen. Why mousemove event still fire when cursor is out of specified element?
[image]
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Code appreciated!

Comment: @Jonasw already there, not familiar with stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the dot, or your tracker, is nested inside of where you are tracking your mousemove, so when you move slowly, this mouse is moving on just the dot, which triggers the mouse move event. You can fix it like this:

```
<!-- change this -->
<div class="a1" id="a1" style="width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px; position:absolute">
    <div id="tracker1">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- to this -->
<div class="a1" id="a1" style="width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px; position:absolute">
</div>

<div id="tracker1">
</div>

<!-- for all 3 instances -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amw2oou9/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the property `overflow: hidden` to `.a1` `.b1` and `.c1` fixes it for me!

Comment: Thanks for response!:)

Comment: Because the tracker will be hidden, once it moves outside the parent box.